# Pl/SQL procedure to rank highest GPA to lowest

Tags: sql, plsql

so I am trying to write a procedure that will rank the highest GPA= 1 and so on using a cursor. Where i am stuck is

```
declare
 snum students.snum%type;
 sname students.sname%type;
 GPA students.GPA%type;
begin 
 for Rec in 
   (select snum,sname,GPA 
      from students
      order by GPA desc)loop
  dbms_output.put_line(rec);
  end loop;
end;
```

I get stuck here in the loop(right now its just a place holder). I am not sure the correct way to set each GPA's rank.

Comment: Don't use a cursor.  Use `rank()` or `row_number()`.

Answer (score 2):

There is RANK function in oracle. [See more here.](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions155.htm)

Example:

```
declare
 v_snum students.snum%type;    --Avoid to use "variable name" as same as "column name"
 v_sname students.sname%type;
 v_GPA students.GPA%type;
begin 
 for rec in 
   (select snum,
           sname, 
           GPA, 
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY GPA desc) as srank
      from students)
 loop
  dbms_output.put_line(rec.snum  || '|' || rec.sname || '|' || rec.GPA || '|' || rec.srank);
 end loop;
end;
```