# Pl/SQL procedure to rank highest GPA to lowest without Rank Function

Tags: sql, plsql, cursor, oracle10g

[Pl/SQL procedure to rank highest GPA to lowest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33577231/pl-sql-procedure-to-rank-highest-gpa-to-lowest)

I'm referring to the question above. Is it possible to rank a student and their GPA without the rank function?

```
FETCH c1 INTO queryResult; 
 INSERT INTO GPA VALUES (queryResult.snum, queryResult.sname, rank,queryResult.OrderFrequency);
 rank := rank + 1;
 EXIT WHEN k = rank;
 END LOOP;
 CLOSE c1;
 COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to rank a student and their GPA without the rank
>   function?

Yes, use plain SQL with left self-join, group by and a count.
But it is expected to be slower than a version using `RANK` function

live demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bde51/7

```
SELECT s1. snum,
       s1.sname,
       s1.gpa,
       count( s2.gpa ) + 1 as rank
FROM students s1
LEFT JOIN students s2
ON s1.GPA < s2.GPA
GROUP BY s1. snum,
         s1.sname,
         s1.gpa
ORDER BY 4;

| SNUM |     SNAME | GPA | RANK |
|------|-----------|-----|------|
|    6 | Student 6 |   4 |    1 |
|    4 | Student 4 |   3 |    2 |
|    3 | Student 3 |   2 |    3 |
|    1 | Student 1 |   2 |    3 |
|    2 | Student 2 |   1 |    5 |
|    5 | Student 5 |   1 |    5 |
```

---

```
select snum,
       sname, 
       GPA, 
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY GPA desc) as srank
from students
ORDER BY 4

| SNUM |     SNAME | GPA | SRANK |
|------|-----------|-----|-------|
|    6 | Student 6 |   4 |     1 |
|    4 | Student 4 |   3 |     2 |
|    1 | Student 1 |   2 |     3 |
|    3 | Student 3 |   2 |     3 |
|    5 | Student 5 |   1 |     5 |
|    2 | Student 2 |   1 |     5 |
```

Comment: Hello if you don't mind me asking, how would I create procedure and cursor using that select statement?